# Disable logging of host lock lease renew calls in Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

Every 5 seconds my Azure Function is logging the http request to Azure blob storage and response to renew the host lock lease. Is there a setting in the logging section of the "host.json" file that will turn these off?

These are "Information" level messages. I've tried setting the log level for "Host" to "Warning" as follows:

```
    {
      "version": "2.0",
      "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
          "default": "Debug",
          "Host": "Warning"
        }
      }
    }
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the few of workaround you can follow:

You can try to add the below cmd to your [`host.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#http) in Function V2:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.MyFunctionName.User": "Information",
      "Function": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

Also based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#disable-built-in-logging):

> To disable built-in logging, delete the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` app
> setting. For information about how to delete app settings in the Azure
> portal, see the **Application settings** section of [How to manage afunction app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings).

For more information please refer this:  [host.json reference for Azure Functions 2.x| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#http) & [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484337/stop-an-azure-function-from-logging-the-executing-and-executed-messages)

Comment: Thank you for the workaround! This does seem to work, although it means every time I add a new function I have to update the host.json file, which is unfortunate. But if there is no logLevel that specifically targets those host lock lease renewal messages, that seems to be the only fix.

Comment: @BrianCampbell Do mind that this will prevent **all** dependencies from being logged!