# How to disable default azure functions logs

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, appinsights

I'm curious if there's a way for overriding the loglevel of the azure function **default** or **built-in** logs.

I've attached a screenshot below with some examples of the unwanted logs.

[image: screenshot of unwanted logs]

I've found out that I can override the setting for **my custom** logs in app.settings by adding this:
AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__LogLevel__Default

Is there a way to differentiate my custom logs from the default logging?

[Stop an Azure Function from logging the “Executing” and “Executed” messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484337/stop-an-azure-function-from-logging-the-executing-and-executed-messages)

I went through this post, but I noticed people complaining about their custom information logs not being logged into app insights anymore.

Also, I've read some Microsoft documentation about a settings **AzureWebJobsDashboard** that you should delete if you want to disable built-in logging. However, I can't find this setting in the azure function app.settings.

I would highly appreciate if someone would clarify this topic for me, I'm kind of a junior with Azure. Also sorry if this post is spam.

Thank you for your time! :D

Answer (score 2):

> Overriding the **loglevel** of the azure function **default** or **built-in** logs

Yes, we can override function log level after deployed into azure.

After deployed in azure if you want to override logging keep adding the **AzureFunctionsJobHost__path__to__setting** setting in Application Settings in function Configuration. If you added the settings in Application
Settings it will override into **`host.json`**

```
AzureFunctionsJobHost__path__to__setting
```

I have added in my function and the `local.settings.json`.  In Below default log level has information **`"default": "Information"`** changing to Debug using **`"AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Default": "Debug"`**.
[image]

After deployment Use portal to override.
[image]

#### Disable the Specific function logging:

In **`host.json`** while logging your function telemetry information we are using log levels and categories [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#disable-built-in-logging). Use **`Log Level`** has **`None`** to disable the specified category log.

```json
  "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information", 
      "Host.Results": "Error", // Host.Results will collect only Error
      "Function": "None", // Disable logging for the Function catagory
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I will try this as soon as possible, thank you! I will try to come back with a result when ready.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue as can be found here:[How to disable durable function verbose logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75437555/how-to-disable-durable-function-verbose-logging/77955703#77955703)

**Is there a way to differentiate my custom logs from the default logging?**
Yes there is

A way to disable the logs of AzureFunctions but not your own logging can be found here: https://github.com/anthonychu/functions-log-suppression

You will have to disable the logging for Functions (or set to whatever Log level you want) and then add the log level for user logging for each function. There is apparently no way to set log level for all user logging so you will sadly need to do it for each function.

Here is an example given by the URL and I have run it locally and it worked for me. in local.stting.json:

```
{
    "logging:logLevel:Microsoft": "None",
    "logging:logLevel:Worker": "None",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:default": "None",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:Host.Function.Console": "Information",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:Function.HttpTrigger1.User": "Information",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:Function.HttpTrigger2.User": "Information"
}
```